# How to pass reactive model statement in GLS for Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, formula

I am trying to pass reactive model statement in GLS so that user can use independent and dependent variable of own choice.

```
covs <- c("TRT01P*AVISIT")
    model <- reactive({
              gls(as.formula(paste(input$sub1,"~",input$sub2,"+",paste(covs,collapse = "+"))),
                  correlation = corSymm(form = ~ 1 | USUBJID),
                  weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | AVISIT),
                  data = data3(),
                 method = "REML")
        })
```

But I am getting error "input not found", though this is working fine in LM function

```
model <- reactive({
      lm(as.formula(paste(input$sub1,"~",input$sub2,"+",paste(covs,collapse = "+"))),
          data = data3())
    })
```

But for my case I have to use GLS function, do I need to update anything in the code?